# How to catch a Notification from an Activity

Tags: android

I have an Activity (ActivityA). This is the starting activity of the app. Then I call a Service (ServiceB) from ActivityA. Then ServiceB liten for some other parameters and makes a notification to the title bar.

```
mNotificationManager.notify(DataHolder.TITLE_BAR_NOTOFICATION_ID, notification);
```

What i want now is ActivityA to also identify that some notification has called. And show that there is a notification.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*What i want now is ActivityA to also identify that some notification has called. And show that there is a notification.*

- The solution is have your Activities to fire custom broadcast and when ActivityA or ActivityB receives that broadcast in `onReceive` method they can show the notification.

**Suppose a scenario is Class1 is doing some task and once a task is complete he wants to notify to other classes.**

```
public class Class1 extends Activity{

    public static final String CUSTOM_INTENT = "org.some.action";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {

        //Do some operation.......now once operation is done send Broadcast 
         to other activities

        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setAction(CUSTOM_INTENT);
        context.sendBroadcast(i);
    }

}
```

**Now Class2 will get notify once a broadcast is received by him.**

```
public class Class2 extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("org.some.action")) {
            System.out.println("I got Notified");
        }
    }
}
```

**Don't forget to add Class2 as receiver in manifest file.**

```
<receiver android:name=".Class2" android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="org.some.action"></action>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: how to do that? if you can link me for a sample that will be really great. Thank you